AKS deployed .NET Core 8 application migrated from .NET Core 3.1 container is running but the application is not started
My .NET Core 8 application in AKS Container is in running start, but its application is not started application is not getting started.
Updated with by inserting container port 8080 instead of 80 updated with env variable in deployment file
    - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
      value: "Demo"
    - name: ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS
      value: "80"
    - name: ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS
      value: "443"
    - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
      value: "http://*:80;https://*:443"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http
    - containerPort: 8081
      name: https 

Exposed port 8080 in docker files and below is my service file
type: ClusterIP
selector:
    env: demo
    app: standard8
ports:
    - targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: http
    - targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      name: https

After running the above deployment & service & deployment file application is getting 502

Check the container logs to see which ports the app is listening on. I would think it listens on 80 & 443 because of your environment variables. 8080 is the new .NET 8 default, but that's only used if you don't set it yourself, which you've done.

@HansKilianStartup : Configuring Container .. this is the container
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed. For more information go tohttps://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarningwarn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
No XML encryptor configured. Key {256e38a3-5492-49a8-97a7-07e91f69be02} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

That is something different no? In that case add- dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage
dotnet add package Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Blobs and then modify your Program.cs to configure data protection to use Azure Blob Storage.

Ideally is a warning but locally when i create a local cer and start the application.Application is getting started..here application is getting stuck not able to start..

Are you getting the pods up? see if there are any errors or messages indicating which ports the application is listening on or log into the container and check which ports are being listened to.
kubectl exec -it <your-pod-name> -- sh
netstat -tuln


Your deployment looks good. Would request you to try once this way and let me know-
ports:         - containerPort: 80           name: http         - containerPort: 443           name: https         env:         - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT           value: "Demo"         - name: ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS           value: "80"         - name: ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS           value: "443"         - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS           value: "http://*:80;https://*:443"

and service as-
`ports:

protocol: TCP
port: 80
targetPort: 80
name: http
protocol: TCP
port: 443
targetPort: 443
name: https`  and see if now Pods are up


In your logs there should be a message like this: Now listening on: http://[::]:8080 which tells you which port(s) it's listening on.

this is what it shows me when i henter into the pod and hit inside itnetstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

@gadeykarthik, do one thing, update your thread with all the necessary details like kubectl logs, pods and their describes and the complete deployment and service yaml along with the docker and program.cs file details for better understanding

@Arko @hans kilan this is the error which is causin the issue Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
Hosting failed to start
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
